# Menu and parameter passing issue

Tags: ros, roslaunch, dynamic-reconfigure, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to ask several things regarding my implementation issue in menu setup.

1. When I set up a menu, just popping up a menu to select at run-time in the terminal, my menu will not be able to be read by user because the terminal is flooded/surrounded by a lot of messages published by other nodes. Perhaps there is a way we can set so that it gives a priority for that node of interest to be read its menu. Any idea to set in launch file? Also,the strange thing, the menu information is not even appeared, even I've coded using ROS_INFO(), not std::cout.
2. When popping up a menu, a user will enter his/her choice, and with that choice it triggers a parameter in my code. How do I do this in ROS because I don't want to pass in argv[] argument. I want the parameter to be set after the command is run, not while the command is run.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44776/menu-and-parameter-passing-issue/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Dynamic reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) seems like a good solution for the problem you describe.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1